# Display widget with based on sibling max width

Tags: layout, flutter

I got a Column, it contains many Text entries of different sizes and I'd like to have them expand to the same width than the largest text.

My Text entries are wrapped in a container with a Color and I want to align all them with the container so it can be rendered with straight borders.

How can I instruct this in Flutter ?

Comment: Does your Column have a fixed with? If so, you could wrap all your children in an Expanded [https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html] so they take alle the space that is available for them.

Comment: No they are text based.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`IntrinsicWidth`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html). You can use it with [`CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html) to determine the intrinsic width of the  children and use it to set the width of your [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html):

[image: screenshot]

Here's the example code that generates the above image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new Material(
        child: new Center(
          child: new IntrinsicWidth(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[200]),
                  child: new Text('Hello'),
                ),
                new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green[200]),
                  child: new Text('world!!!!!!!'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's important to note that the intrinsicWidth wouldnt be calculated correct if it wasn't wrapped within a center. Due to the center widget it gets its constraint set right. I ran into this problem, when I wasnt adding the right alignment above my IntriniscWidth widget.